# How to include dummy phoenix app as part of a library

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If you're familiar with Rails, there's `test/dummy` rails app inside Engine plugins that's used for testing and whatnot.

How would I go about including something like that my library? I need that phoenix app so I can work with a view that renders some data from Ecto models. I don't want that dummy app to be compiled with the rest of my library. I could technically make a separate repo, but I wonder is there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If it's purely for development purpose, it would be the best of you create a Phoenix app in umbrella mode and add your library as normal umbrella child app.

That way, you can use Phoenix but it is completely decoupled from your lib and just uses your lib as a dependency as any other user would do.

Example commands to set it up:

```
mix phx.new my_lib_dev --umbrella

cd my_lib_dev_umbrella/apps

mix new my_lib
```

Then in `my_lib_dev_umbrella/apps/my_lib_dev_web/mix.exs` you can add your lib as dependency with `{:my_lib, in_umbrella: true}`.

Now you are able to develop your lib in `my_lib_dev_umbrella/apps/my_lib`, completely decoupled from Phoenix itself but your Phoenix setup includes it as dependency and behaves as it would have been pulled by a user from Hex.

If you are new to umbrella setups, you can read more about it here:
[Umbrella Projects · Elixir School](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/advanced/umbrella-projects/)

Comment: Is there an example of this kind of setup? Just to clarify, does that mean a completely separate project from the lib then?

Comment: Hey, I edited my post with example commands. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: To get back to your question. No, it's not really a separate project. It's more of a container around your lib. `my_lib_dev_umbrella/apps/my_lib` is your whole library which you push to GitHub and publish on Hex. Everything around that is just the helper setup for development.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So then I can just publish just the lib app. Seems like it created a full-blown phoenix app for the non-web portion though. I just noticed `elixirc_paths` key for `project` method. Maybe it's less of a hasle just to keep `dummy` in the root folder and link lib from there.